# Unable to Open or Download Linked Attachment Downloads from Outlook in IE9

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-outlook-2007, internet-explorer-9

I am using Windows Professional 7, Microsoft Outlook 2007, and IE9.  When I receive an e-mail with large attachments, my e-mail provider removes the attachment and replaces it with a download link.  When I click the download link, I am redirected to the IE9 Downloads window and given the option to open or save the attachment.  Regardless of whether I choose to save or open the file, I receive the following error:  "This file couldn't be downloaded."  (Note:  the file appears to fully download before I receive this error message).

I do not experience this problem with Firefox.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try upgrading to Internet Explorer 10? I believe that that fixes some bugs in older versions of Internet Explorer.

Comment: @gparyani I tried installing IE10 but got an error message that I could not install it because I did not have SP1.

Comment: (If this is your computer) Upgrade to Windows 7 Service Pack 1, then install Internet Explorer 10.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following process:

- Go to the Temporary Internet Files folder:

  - %LocalAppData%\Microsoft\Windows\Temporary Internet Files
- Delete everything

**References**

- [Temporary Internet Files Folder location in Windows 7 / 8](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/temporary-internet-files-folder-location)
- [View and delete your browsing history in Internet Explorer - Windows Help](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/17438/windows-internet-explorer-view-delete-browsing-history)